# Moving Rows to Different Sheet Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to move rows from a specific tab of Doc 1, to row 2 of Doc 2. Right now the data is importing into row 1 of Doc 2, causing the column headers to be removed. I'm newer to scripts, so I'm thinking this should be a simple update, but haven't been able to figure it out.

```html
function CopyDataToTopicPool() {
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('12ioAv8zkSieB0_1KjWW4G9EioyPhfyEtDcppMq2Xlwg'); // sss = source spreadsheet
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Need New Topic Ideas'); // ss = source sheet
  //Get full range of data
  var SRange = ss.getDataRange();
  //get A1 notation identifying the range
  var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();
  //get the data values in range
  var SData = SRange.getValues();

  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Gaan3bV6Rkih7cJrXGOlHeCqufwvb8oYUfl9xw2QTcQ'); // tss = target spreadsheet
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // ts = target sheet
  //set the target range to the values of the source data
  ts.getRange(A1Range).setValues(SData);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set the values in your target sheet `ts.getRange(A1Range).setValues(SData);` , you used the original range `A1Range` of your source sheet. It will basically copy the data in the source sheet and paste it to your destination sheet on the exact same range/location.

What you need to do is to specify the ranges where you want to set the values in your target sheet using [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)

**It should be like this:**

```
ts.getRange(2,1,SRange.getLastRow(),SRange.getLastColumn()).setValues(SData);
```

- The range that is selected will start at row index 2 and column 1.
- It will set the last row and column index based on the size of your range using [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getlastrow) and [getLastColumn()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getlastcolumn)

**Example Source Sheet:**

[image]

**Example Destination Sheet:**

[image]